# Enable EPEL repository in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, git, repository, centos7

I tried to enabled my EPEL repository in my CentOS system because some packages were not available in the official CentOS 7 repository.
I followed this tutorial:

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

and followed `RHEL/CentOS 7 64 Bit` part.

I tried

> RHEL/CentOS 7 64-Bit

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

But I get this error:

```
resolving dl.fedoraproject.org (dl.fedoraproject.org)... failed: Name or service not known.    
wget: unable to resolve host address dl.fedoraproject.org
```

Do any of you know how to fix this?
I tried googling it but did not point me to the right answer.

Comment: why did you download it yourself?  why not let `yum` take care of it for you?  Try `yum install epel-release`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Is there any reason for a successful yum update to cause a subsequent wget to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25320088/6309)", you might want to try:

```
sudo yum update
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the comment of chicks (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2002471). For me this was the answer I was looking for:

```
yum install epel-release
```

The links to fedora seem to change time by time. I found links to epel-release-7-5, others to epel-release-7, current (2/2018) seems to be epel-release-7-9.